# Doctrine QueryBuilder addSelect with user input

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm using the Doctrine QueryBuilder in my Silex project. I'm building a query, completely based on user input. The parameters are escaped with the `setParameter()` function. But how about the `addSelect()`?

I can't figure this out, is it save to do something like this:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->createQueryBuilder()
    ->addSelect("`".$userinputCol1."`")
    ->addSelect("`".$userinputCol2."`")
    ->from('`mytable`')
    ->where('id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $userinputId)
    ->execute();
```

Will this prevent SQL injection in the SELECT?

Comment: Can't you use a parameter? `addSelect(':userInputCol1')`

Comment: @Veve No. Then it will be escaped in single quotes

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would not pass user input straight into a `QueryBuilder` method, even escaping it.  I would do something like this:

```
    $possibleSelectFields = ['name', 'dob', 'created', 'something'];
    if (!in_array($userInputCol1, $possibleSelectFields) || !in_array($userInputCol2, $possibleSelectFields)) {
        throw new \Exception("Throw an exception, or just silently ignore the user\'s input - depending on how bad this situation is for your application.");
    }

    //...Your code as before
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it's much more defensive - perhaps there might be a column that query could expose that you would never want a user to be able to see - this approach avoids that problem.

Comment: That is indeed true. I will fix that issue to.